# React Native App not connecting via WebSocket after publishing it on the Play Store

Tags: django, react-native, websocket, django-channels, daphne

In my application I have implemented real time application with socket and django channels that I deployed with daphne (ws://api.xxxxx.com).

It works perfectly with my react native app in the development mode, where I just connect with javascript code:

`let socket = new WebSocket(ws://api.xxxxx.com)`.

But the problem was when I published the app on the play store, which I just can't know why it's not connecting since I don't have any log showing the refusal of connection.

These are the logs from daphne in the development mode:

```
1xx.x.x.x.x:45xxx - - [09/Dec/2020:23:27:34] "WSCONNECTING /ws/xxxxx/90/" - -
1xx.x.x.x.x:45xxx - - [09/Dec/2020:23:27:34] "WSCONNECT /ws/xxxxx/90/" - -
```

With the play store version app, the daphne logs are just empty. Can anyone help me on how to solve this?

Comment: have you tried building it for production and testing it locally? you can plug the log server and see errors. 
npx react-native log-android

Comment: Do you mean to build the signed apk and try to run with it?

Comment: Yes. Build it and try to run it with error log server